# General assembly-lesson 5 checkpoint 16 (defining a keyframe)

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm extremely green with coding and I'm currently on project 5 checkpoint 16, the project is asking me to define a keyframe to make the robots eyes blink but I don't know what im doing wrong with my syntax.

```
@keyframes blink {50% {
background: radial-gradiant(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;}
```

this is the current syntax I have written down but apparently its not correct, any help of guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a closing `}` and you miss-spelled `gradient` as `gradiant`. Other than that, you're fine.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: blink 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    background: radial-gradient(circle, red 15%, transparent 40%), #cc5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```